# Thread.Abort stop all threads or just current. Smart to use Abort?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
    RulyCanceler canceler = new RulyCanceler();
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try { Work(canceler, crawler, propertyBag); }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            LogError.WriteError("Working thread canceled!" + Environment.NewLine);
            LogError.WriteError(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogError.WriteError(e);
        }
    });
    workerThread.Start();

    bool finished = workerThread.Join(120000);
    if (!finished)
    {
        LogError.WriteError("Aborting thread");
        workerThread.Abort();
    }
```

I can not figure out if my program stop all threads when Abort is calling or just current thread and program still executing. Sometime program stop unexepected but i do not know if abort is guilty. Can someone tell me?

EDIT:

I modify class like John suggest

```
class RulyCanceler
    {    
        readonly object _cancelLocker = new object();
        bool _cancelRequest;

        private bool IsCancellationRequested
        {
            get { lock (_cancelLocker) return _cancelRequest; }
        }

        public void Cancel() { lock (_cancelLocker) _cancelRequest = true; }

        public void ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        {
            if (IsCancellationRequested) throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }
    }

class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var canceler = new RulyCanceler();
    new Thread (() => {
                        try { Work (canceler); }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException)
                        {
                          Console. WriteLine ("Canceled! ");
                        }
                      }). Start();
    Thread. Sleep (1000);
    canceler. Cancel();               // Safely cancel worker.
  }
  static void Work (RulyCanceler c)
  {
    while (true)
    {
      c. ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      // . . .
      try      { OtherMethod (c); }
      finally  { /* any required cleanup */ }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.Abort` will only abort the thread which you call it on. However, it's a really bad way of terminating a thread - you should do it in a more controlled and cooperative way. Thread.Abort is a safe way of aborting the currently executing thread, but otherwise you don't know that the thread is at a suitable place to abort without leaving the application in an inconsistent state. You should usually reserve it for times when your whole application is going down anyway.

Comment: thx for answer. so how you advice me to abort thread if executing to long?

Comment: @senzacionale: Your worker should periodically check whether the calling code is trying to cancel it. For example, you might have a shared flag for this purpose - or if you're using .NET 4, you can use the Task Parallel Library which has a cancellation mechanism built in.

Comment: shared flag? Can you give me an example please how do you mean with flag? And yes i am porting application to .net 4.0 already.

Comment: By "shared flag" Jon meant something like this: http://unethicalblogger.com/node/31 - this is the most trivial and straightforward way to cancel a thread safely.

Comment: thx both. I modify RulyCanceler like you suggest. I copy it if anyone need it too.

Comment: I think CancellationTokens are the preferred implementation of such a flag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what's taking your application down then attach an event handler to the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event and log the stacktrace (or set a debug break point).